# Creating date based back entries for a blog and its site registration

Tags: domain-registration, blog

So I am showing a blog to a colleague and telling him how the author has been regularly blogging for over ten years now. My colleague tells me that anyone can register a domain name and start entries from say circa 2000. When I argued that the site registration date can easily show that the registration was done recently he put forward two arguments:

1. The author can claim that he moved from an old domain name which was registered many years ago and lapsed. So he took the data and rebuilt it in the new site.
2. The author can buy an expired domain which was on the internet for many years.

I am not sure if these ways can work to con someone to believing you have been a blogger for over a decade. But I do not have enough expertise in the topic to refute him.

So I thought I would ask the wise community here at StackExchange. Can anyone give me some insight?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your work friend is mistaken, basically when a domain expires after the redemption period it is released to the public... All records of the domains are deleted. When re-registering the new date will be shown.

*Now there are a few possibilities that would lead your friend to this conclusion:*

1. Using a whois that uses cached results.
2. Using a whois that displays first registered in year X.
3. Auctioned domains do not technically expire therefor it would not be a new registration, so the date would not change.

I would imagine that in certain cases it would be possible to change the registration date but in no way do I imagine they would do it for periods you was not owning the domain, therefor the new date which be shown... In fact they do not even have a written policy on their site because to me its a obvious no....

Its like asking someone to back date a receipt for periods you did not own the item, ask your friend to cite official information either from ICANN or Nominate that contains this information.